# How to share your localhost from one machine to another in windows?

Tags: localhost, share, firewall, ipconfig

To share your localhost to other :
For some reasons, while working on code you may need to share your work in localhost to others , In windows it is way more easier to share your localhost from one machine to another. Here how you do this

```
First : Win + R , open Terminal and search ipconfig or ipconfig/all
It will show your Windows IP Configuration 


Find your IP
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : xxx.xxx.x.xx                                                                                                                    
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : xxx.xxx.xxx.x                                                                                                                       
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : xxx.xxx.x.x  


Make sure your firewall allow connection
Try opening your browser and put your IP to access the localhost(Read/Write)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on the same network `xx.xx.xxx.xx:port` (`123.12.110.12:3000`)